# What is the legal definition of "surrender" when it comes to leases in the US?

Tags: definition, colorado, lease, tenant

My lease says "DEPOSIT RETURN, SURRENDER, AND ABANDONMENT OR JUDICIAL EVICTION. We'll mail you your security deposit refund (less lawful deductions) and an itemized accounting of any deductions no later than 60 days after surrender or abandonment, unless statutes provide otherwise." [My reading of the legal definition of "surrender" is that it is an "abnormal" giving up of lease.](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/surrender) If I left an apartment at the legal end of the lease and have not received my security deposit within a month, is the landlord in violation of [§38-12-103 C.R.S.](http://www.tenant.net/Other_Areas/Colorado/crs/103.html) and therfore subject to section 2 of that paragraph?

This is the only mention of a 60 day time period in the whole lease, so I am assuming that the "one month" in the law applies to "normal" end of lease.

Comment: The statute says "unless the lease agreement specifies a longer period of time, but not to exceed sixty days." I've often heard the term "surrender the keys" which just means turning over any keys you have to the landlord/management company. I think it applies to official lease end or any other time you turn over the keys.

Comment: @mkennedy is correct.  Surrender implies giving up possession, it does not imply anything "abnormal" about the way in which the possession of the property occurred, and they have 60 days.